# What is the average temperature in Kochi during mid-October?

Tags: india, weather-and-climate, kerala

I know that weather in Kerala can be tricky in October, as it's [between two monsoon seasons](http://www.kerala.gov.in/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3666%3awater-resources&catid=824%3asector). I know that there's a likelihood of rain, but I haven't been able to find reliable information about the *temperature range* for the middle to end of October in the Kochi area of Kerala. (The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_India#Temperature) on the climate of India only has data for Kerala's capital Thiruvananthapuram, which is over 200km/125 miles farther south than Kochi. While that's okay for me to estimate, I'd love to have concrete data about Kochi itself.)

Additionally, the Kerala Tourism website [doesn't say anything](http://www.kerala-tourism.org/climate-of-kerala/index.html) about the climate of northern Kerala in the fall, only that the southern and inland areas bear the brunt of the northeast monsoon.

Can anyone tell me what the average daily temperature range is for Kochi during this time? Also, what is the average humidity level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently during the month of October, the weather [is described as 'pleasant'](http://www.mustseeindia.com/Kochi-weather):

> Temperature varies from 22 to 31°C.
>   October has intermittent post monsoon showers.
>   The climate is moderate and good for outings.

Answer (score 5):

Kochi, like most Indian coastal cities along the Arabian Sea, has [moderate temperature without much fluctuation throughout the year](http://www.weatherbase.com/weather/weatherall.php3?s=35334&refer=&units=metric&cityname=Cochin-Kerala-India) (the link says Cochin because that was the old name of this city). In October it ranges from 25 to 29 degree Celsius. It's also one of the months when Kochi receives the most rainfall in most years (same link) so expect monsoon showers and high humidity throughout. [Most of the October monsoon showers come from retreating monsoon winds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsoon#Northeast_monsoon) which blow clouds from eastern to western sea-board, so Kochi comparatively will still receive less rainfall than east coast.

I haven't been to Kochi specifically in October but basically, be prepared for rains. Weather in general will be pleasant though.

Comment: Hmm. October is **not** the month with most rainfall, according to your link and [Mark's](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2187/what-is-the-average-temperature-in-kochi-during-mid-october/2189#2189) too. (June and July are.)

Comment: My bad, I meant "one of the". Edited answer. You'll see though that than July, October is the month when it sees the highest number of days with thundershowers as well as centimetres of rainfall, which is because of the retreating monsoon.

Comment: No worries. :) Still, as to "centimetres of rainfall", October isn't 2nd after July (it's 4th). From the same link, "Average precipitation": Jun 56 cm, Jul 52 cm, Aug 34 cm, **Oct 31 cm**. (In "avg # of days with thunderstorms" Oct is 2nd after May.)

Comment: Ah I see where I went wrong, I was looking at *most* rainfall. My bad again. :)

Comment: Also, October's third on list of months with most thundershowers.

Comment: Ah, true. (It's also #3, together with Aug, in "most rain reported in a month".)

Answer (score 3):

Disregard the average stats, it's hitting 35 degrees C nowadays in the central parts of Kerala - which is where Kochi is.

October in Kerala is called the *2nd summer* among the locals - it's because the post-monsoon coolness of September is gone, and it's a month away for the cooler winter. The main problem for any visitors will be humidity.

It's averaging 80% nowadays and will be the same around October too.

Note - I'm from Kerala so a bit of first-hand info there.

Comment: How do you figure that Kochi is in the interior of Kerala? Unless there are two cities called Kochi in Kerala...the one I'm referring to is undoubtedly a coastal city.

Comment: Nope, I meant only central as in North - Central - South. There is only one Kochi, and that is coastal. Not the interiors.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I still have some issues with this answer. First, it doesn't give me information specifically about Kochi, which I asked for a) because Kerala is a long state north-south, and b) weather is different between coastal and inland areas. Also, [several](http://www.weather.com/weather/monthly/INXX0032) weather [sites](http://www.accuweather.com/en-us/in/kerala/kochi/forecast2.aspx) don't report Kochi as currently being more than the normal high of 29-31 C. Even if it were, you have no way of knowing that it will remain unseasonably warm a month from now.

Comment: That being said, thank you for being the only one so far to address the humidity part of the question.

Comment: Sorry this answer doesn't work for you. When I saw the 1uestion, I had a quick chat with my dad who lives 50 kilometres north of Kochi, and then posted. This might not match weather sites, but I would not rely too much on those for India other than big cities. Do let me know how things were after the trip in October.

Comment: This answer does contain some useful information (the second summer thing and the humidity data), but I'm trying to let you know how it could be better. Even the fact that you spoke to your dad who lives near Kochi affects the authority of your answer - and since this site is all about expert answers, any relevant information should be included in your answer. Don't mean to discourage you from answering; quite the opposite.  But good answers typically contain references or full backstory on why you're an expert. :)

Comment: Atleast, as far as weather is concerned, I would trust a local than any expert. :)

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, it was about 31°C every day that I was in the Kochi area. A weather forecast a few days before I arrived told me to expect rain showers every day, but it only rained once and it was at night. Humidity was definitely high, which should be expected in the tropics. JoseK's estimate of around 80% humidity seems accurate to me. The temperature seemed to fit in what Mark Mayo found as the average range.

Comment: hey just saw this - so my local knowledge was a bit right